# Error and data callback parameters in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

It seems to me a good and widely used practice to build callback routines in Node.js according to the following pattern.

> callback (error, data)

The following experience I have done so far.

- In case of a successful execution, *error* is `null` or `undefined` and data contains the desired information.
- In case of an erroneous execution, there are two possibilities.

  - *error* contains an object with error infomation and *data* is `null` or `undefined`
  - *error* contains a string with the name of the error and data contains optionally additional error information.

The first variant appears to me more meaningful, since the parameters do not change their semantic independently of the execution result.

And therefore my actual question.

Is there an accepted standard or guideline that describes the structure of callback routines in Node.js and gives you an idea of how this should be, or even have to be?

Comment: What about `Promise`? :)

Comment: Right, the use of a `Promise` result is unambiguous. But callbacks...

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convention. There can be more params after error as well.

You can even do it your way in `yourStyle()`

```
nodeStyle(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    // error
  } else {
    // success
  }
};

yourStyle(params, function (data) {
  if (isError(data)) {
    // error
  } else {
    // success
  }
};

promiseStyle(params)
  .then(function (data) {
    // success
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    // error
  });
```